# Segmentation fault in file I/O, cannot figure out

Tags: file-io, segmentation-fault, c89

Basically, I have rewritten code that kept giving me a segmentation fault (core dump) error when running, and I decided to check each step to rule out issues.

My code works, until I try accessing/using the last line of the input files data. I do the same things to this line as to the line previous, but it's suggesting somethings wrong.

Here is my code for the file I/O and data handling:

[image]

The input file itself is simply:

```
20 20
10 10 u
5 5 d
```

Comment: Just as an aside, the usual practice is to include your code in the question itself, and as text rather than an image. You want to do as much as possible to make it easier for us to help you. Given your newness to the site, we can probably forgive that once, but you would be well advised to do so in future so your questions aren't closed unnecessarily. Normally I would fix that for newcomers but that's a lot of code for me to transcribe, especially when you can just cut'n'paste the text much easier.

Comment: That last sentence of mine above is a suggestion for what you should do to *this* question by the way. Don't wait for the next question :-)

Comment: And you can format code in a couple of ways. One is to prefix every line of code with four spaces (more if you want indents). I've fixed your question in the other way, by starting the code block with three backticks (and the language) such as `<backtick><backtick><backtick>c++`, and ending it with just three backticks. These backtick lines need to be on their own line.

Comment: Eeknormous, since you haven't yet pasted the code in as text, I guess I can at least bring the *image* into the question and resize it so it's readable so we don't have to follow a link to get to it. However, you really should replace that with the text at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In line 27, you dereference the uninitialised `playerDirInput`, which is undefined behaviour:

```c
playerDir = (char)playerDirInput[0];
```

That's *probably* the cause of your crash. If that code block is meant to mirror the following one, it looks like you just haven't read the third item on that line, which is where `playerDirInput` is probably meant to come from. That would be something like:

```c
fgets(line, 8, f);

playerRowChar = strtok(line, " ");
playerRow = atoi(playerRowChar);

playerColChar = strtok(NULL, " ");    // <- fixed this, see below.
playerCol = atoi(playerColChar);

playerDirInput = strtok(NULL, " ");   // <- add this.
playerDir = (char)playerDirInput[0];
```

---

However, I would suggest you instead opt for the simpler `sscanf` version, which would go something like (including a check to ensure you get the three items):

```c
fgets(line, 8, f);
if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %c", &playerRow, &playerCol, &playerDir) != 3) {
    handleErrorIntelligently();
}
```

I tend to prefer `fgets` followed by `sscanf`, rather than `fscanf`. The latter can fail in such a way that you're not sure where the input stream pointer ends up as. With `fgets`, you always know you've read a line (or can easily detect that you read a partial line and adjust for it).

---

Other potential problems you should look at:

- On line 25, this `strtok` should be of the `NULL` type, not `line`. The latter will simply re-read the first item on that line wheras you want the next item.
- You really should *check* functions that can return problematic values (such as `NULL` from `strtok`). Otherwise, using them can cause issues. That depends on the data you're reading, of course, so may not necessarily be a problem if you control that.